# View Count not working

Tags: channel-entries, tracking

I was using view count on one of my templates, and recently I noticed it had stopped working. The only thing which is different about my set-up since the last time i noticed it was working was

1. I am now using Focus Lab's Master Config instead of the regular config file
2. I have set up both APC and Memcache, to speed up the site.

Will any of these things stop view count from working and if so, is there a way around it?

I have added `$env_config['relaxed_track_views'] = 'y';` to the master config file but no success so far.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ce Cache? If your cache is delivering pre-rendered flat content then your channel entries tags are going to get bypassed, and your count won't increment. If you check your viewcount, empty the cache and request that page again does your count increment?

Comment: Native EE view tracking very likely isn't working on account of the caching, as mentioned here. On our projects, we always disable EE's view/tracking mechanisms to improve performance, and rely on a third party (i.e. Google Analytics) for stats.